# Number of active connections on the server reached to max

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverless-framework, replicaset

I am working with mongodb and nodejs. I have mongodb hosted on Atlas.

My backend had been working perfectly but now it is sometimes getting stuck and when I see the analytics on mongodb atlas it shows maximum number of active connections reached to **100**.

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Can I reboot the connections and make it **0**?

**@Stennie** I have used mongoose to connect to database

Here is my configuration file

```
const mongooseOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  autoReconnect: true,
  poolSize: 25,
  connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000
} 

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  defaults = Hoek.applyToDefaults(defaults, options)

  if (Mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    return next()
  }

  if (!Mongoose.connection.readyState) {
    server.log(`${process.env.NOED_ENV} server connecting to ${defaults.url} ${defaults.url}`)

    return Mongoose.connect(defaults.url, mongooseOptions).then(() => {
      return next() // call the next item in hapi bootstrap
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your backend is deployed on lambda since serverless tag.

Each invocation will leave a container idle to prevent cold start, or use an existing one if available. You are leaving the connection open to reuse it between invocation, like advertised in [best practices](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-to-aws-lambda/).

With a `poolSize` of 25 (?) and 100 max connections, you should limit your [function concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/per-function-concurrency.html) to 4.

> Reserve concurrency to prevent your function from using all the available concurrency in the region, or from overloading downstream resources.

More reading: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs

Comment: Yes my back end is on lambda. And well Not much I could get from the above answer but as far as I understand "Each deploy command will create a new mongo connection!!!" So can I `sudo serverless remove -s <stag>` command to stop and start my service? So that all existing connections will break down?

Comment: Not deploy but invocation, each container should be removed after ~30 minutes of inactivity, the mongo server should release the sessions by itself after a certain timeout. If you want to manually release stale connections you should be able to kill those with compas or command line.

Answer (score 7):

You could try couple of things:

1. In a `serverless` environment, as already suggested by @Gabriel Bleu, why have such a high `connectionLimit`. `Serverless` environment keeps spawning new containers and stopping as per requests. If multiple instances spawn concurrently, it would exhaust the MongoDB server limit very quickly.
2. The concept of `connectionPool` is, `x` number of connections are established every time from every node (instance). But that does not mean all the connections are automatically released after querying. After completing **ALL** the DB operation, you should `release` each connection individual after use: `mongoose.connection.close();`

**Note:** Mongoose connection close will close all the connections of connection pool. So ideally, this should be run just before returning the response.

3. Why are you setting explicity `autoReconnect` to true. [MongoDB driver internally](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html) reconnects whenever the connection is lost and certainly is not recommended for short lifespan instances such as `serverless containers`.
4. If you are running in `cluster` mode, to optimize for performance, change the `serverUri` to replica set URL format: `MONGODB_URI=mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostOne>,<hostTwo>,<hostThree>...&ssl=true&authSource=admin`.

Comment: #2 Do you mean every query is itself makes a new connection?

Comment: No. When you set `connectionLimit` to 25 (default is 5), all the 25 `connections` are opened(against `serverQuota`-here 100)to the server(active connections), even if there are not many requests. And once the `connections` are opened, for each and every query, a connection will be used from the said pool only. If all the 25 connections are exhausted by queries, then the 26th query will have to wait until one of the `25 queries` release (not close) the connection. So,Unless you are making `25 parallel queries` (mind you NodeJs async nature),it does not make a valid point for such a high limit.

Comment: @Profer Each Query doen't initiate new connection but the older connection which is persisted previously will be used, here the glitch is there will be a little time between queries so the connection will be idle for that time. instead of keeping it idle, best practise it to terminate the connection once query is done, so it will not exhaust the connection pool

Answer (score 5):

There are so many factors affecting the `max connection limit`. You have `mongoDB` hosted on Atlas and as you mentioned the backend is `lamda` means you have a serverless environment.

1. Serverless environments spawn new container on the new connection and destroy a connection when it's no longer being used. The `peak` connection shows that there are so many new instances being initialized or so many concurrent requests from the user connection. The best practice is to terminate database connection once it's no longer needed. You can terminate the connection
   `mongoose.connection.close();` as you have used `mongoose`. It will release the connection from the connection pool. Rather exhausting the concurrent connection limit, you should release connection once it's idle.
2. Your configuration forces the database driver to reconnect after the connection is dropped by the database. You are explicitly setting the `autoReconnect` as `true` so the driver will quickly instantiate connection request once the connection is dropped. That may affect the `concurrent connection limit`. You should avoid setting it explicitly.
3. `cluster mode` can optimize the requests according to the load, you can change the server uri to the replica of database. it may help to migrate the load.
4. There is a small initial startup cost of approximately 5 to 10 seconds when the Lambda function is invoked for the first time and the MongoDB client in your AWS Lambda function connects to MongoDB. Connections to a `mongos` for a sharded cluster are faster than connecting to a replica set. Subsequent connections will be significantly faster for the duration of the lifecycle of the Lambda function. so Each invocation will leave a container idle to prevent `cold start` or `cold boot`, or use an existing one if available.
5. Atlas sets the limit for concurrent incoming connections to a cluster based on the cluster tier. If you try to connect when you are at this limit, MongoDB displays an error stating “connection refused because too many open connections”. You can close any open connections to your cluster not currently in use. scaling down to a higher tier to support more concurrent connections. as mentioned in best practice you may `restart` the application. To prevent this issue in the future, consider utilizing the maxPoolSize connection string option to limit the number of connections in the connection pool.
6. Final Solution to this issue is Upgrading to a larger Atlas cluster tier which allows a greater number of connections. if your user base is too large for your current cluster tier.